# RxSwift exit from observable chain if text is empty

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I'm having trouble understanding the way to early exit from an observable sequence if I don't have the necessary info. Here's a simplified example...

```
@IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField!
...
myButton.rx.tap. // stop here if textField is nil or empty
.flatMap { API.fetchMyList() }
.subscribe...
```

Comment: Can you instead keep the button disabled unless there's at least one (presumably non-whitespace) character in the text field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’ll want to transform your observable chain to include the content of the text field, and then filter out the values you are not interested in. The operator `withLatestFrom` will pull values from another observable into the current chain.

```
@IBOutlet weak var myTextField: UITextField!

myButton.rx.tap
.withLatestFrom(myTextField.rx.text)
.filter { $0 != nil && $0?.isEmpty == false }
.flatMapLatest { // here $0 is the value of the text field
  API.fetchMyList($0) 
}
.subscribe...
```

As a side note, you’ll probably want to use flatMapLatest in lieu of flatMap, so that old requests get canceled if another tap of button occurs.